# Cordova plugin not available anymore to install "com.contraterrene.GapFile": "1.1.0",

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a old project to maintain which is using a Cordova Plugin called GapFile but it seems to be taken away from github. Here is the link for it https://github.com/tonyhursh/gapfile.git

How can I get this plugin? Or an alternate?

Thanks

Comment: What is about this plugin, Why do you want to use this.

Comment: @Zaheer These are the ones which i found close to what you are looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-node-like https://gist.github.com/rally25rs/e93e441c439eeeb82ba8

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... The original author was kind enough to send me the plugin and now I am able to run the application. I have request author's permission to upload the plugin on github and waiting for his response.